# How can I cut the flavour of Worcestershire sauce in a completed Asian dish?

Tags: sauce, asian-cuisine

I was following a [Chicken Yakisoba recipe](https://www.budgetbytes.com/2012/03/chicken-yakisoba/) that looked good. I ended up doubling the sauce because I had added extra cabbage and other vegetables. The sauce called for:

> - 1/4 cup soy sauce
> - 1/4 cup worcestershire sauce
> - 2 Tbsp ketchup
> - up to 1 Tbsp sriracha hot sauce
> - 1 Tbsp sugar

I double all there except I kept the sriracha sauce to 1 Tbsp. I was wary of adding 1/2 cup of Worcestershire but I only really started cooking recently so I do not have experience to know better. The resulting sauce was powerful to say the least. While it is edible it is not something I am super proud of. Next time I will reduce the amount. After reading comments on this some other people had similar issues.

For now I have 4-5 servings of this dish that I do not want to throw out. I hate waste. However I would like to try and salvage the dish.

What can I do to try and cut the Worcestershire sauce in my already completed Chicken Yakisoba?

Comment: This recipe looks somewhat unusual in that there is a /lot/ of Worcestershire sauce. In the recipes I'm familiar with, there is usually more ketchup

Comment: The bottle I had is not even designed for dispensing that amount efficiently. Last time I trust the internet.

Comment: Oh yeah, the little thing inside the top of the bottle. My recipe also calls for a ton of Worcestershire sauce, so I end up removing it usually.

Answer (score 5):

I have never encountered this problem but I would suggest making up a batch of just the sauce, omitting the Worcestershire sauce and maybe going a little light on any of the other ingredients that would contribute a high salt content. I would make sure to cook the sauce till the raw flavor is gone, then I would add that to the remaining Chicken Yakisoba you have. Good luck, I hope everything works out.